# How to access class variable from deep-nested child

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

How to access class variable within deep-nested child?

Scenario: class with public variable myVar and I want to access it from sixth child.

I am looking for less stupid way than `MovieClip(parent.parent.parent.parent.parent).myVar` (which works)

**Edit**: It's an customizable avatar, with different animations. There will be more than one avatar on the stage. - Works well with dispatchEvents

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is the Event system, as it allows you to avoid this kind of headache.

Say you have a MovieClip called `container` and you want it's 6th child to be able to communicate with it.

Simply add an event listener to your container like this :

```
addEventListener("HelloItsMeTheSixthChild", sixthChildHandler);

function sixthChildHandler(e:Event):void
{
   var sixthChild:MovieClip = e.target as MovieClip;

   // now do whatever you want with that sixthChild
   // maybe call a method of sixthChild that utilizes this instance ?
   sixthChild.doStuff(this);

}

  // in your sixthChild's class
  function doStuff(uberParent:MovieClip):void
  {
       uberParent.scaleX = 5;
       uberParent.scaleY = 6;
  }
```

In  your sixthChild's class you'd just dispatch an event to execute that communication and result :

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("HelloItsMeTheSixthChild", true));
```

if you are going to be using that this distant relative often, you could also just pass a reference into that sixthChild and store it in a class variable :

```
// in your sixthChild's class 

public var uberParent:MovieClip;

function setUberParent(uParent:MovieClip):void
{
    uberParent = uParent;
}


function doStuffWithMyUberParent():void
{
    uberParent.rotation = 90;
}
```

So just a couple ways of communicating with distant relatives. However, I think there are indeed better ways to design your application so that you don't have to think about things like this as much.

For instance, I don't think it's a good idea for your sixth child to be doing something to that uberParent. I think it should be just communicating via events and let the parent react to those events. That way if I look at the uberParent's code, I have a really good idea of what's happening and there isn't this rogue child out there that can change it's properties at a whim.

Answer (score 3):

Generally this type of tight-coupling is representative of a greater desigin pattern issue.

#### Static approach

If there's only one ascendant parent class, such as an overarching game instance, you could access a static variable.

Game class, containing the `myVar` instance:

```
package
{
    public class Game
    {
        public static var myVar:String;
    }
}
```

Then, any class can access the variable by:

```
Game.myVar
```

#### Singleton approach

Likewise, if there's only one ascendant parent class, a singleton class could be implemented:

```
package
{
    public class Game
    {
        /** Data model */
        public var myVar:String;

        /** Singleton instance */
        private static var _instance:Game = new Game();

        /** Return singleton instance */
        public static function getInstance():Game
        {
            return _instance;
        }

        /** Constructor as singleton enforcer */
        public function Game()
        {
            if (_instance)
                throw new Error("Game is a singleton and can only be accessed through Game.getInstance()");
        }
    }
}
```

Get the instance of the singleton class to access the variable:

```
var game:Game = Game.getInstance();
game.myVar;
```

#### Sets within collections

With both the static and singleton approaches, you can map instances within a dictionary.

For example, say you had multiple ascendant parent classes.  Each instance could be mapped within a collection, perhaps in an application model class:

```
// collection, referencing parent instance
public var map:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

// myVar variable from different parent instances:
map[parent1] = myVar;
map[parent2] = myVar;
```

#### Encapsulation

If models truly need to be passed to children, you could encapsulate the functionality to pass the variable down.

In this example, the parent maintains control of the child by setting the child's `myVar` variable when its own `myVar` property is set:

```
package
{
    public class Game
    {

        private var _myVar:String;

        public function get myVar():String
        {
            return _myVar;
        }

        public function set myVar(value:String):void
        {
            _myVar = value;
            child.myVar = value;
        }

    }
}
```

This way, when the ascendant parent class sets the variable, it copies the value down to child models.

This makes sense for presentation models, such as models backing controls and UI components; however, I wouldn't typically recommend this.

#### Inversion of Control (IoC)

[Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) by [inversion of control (IoC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) is a design pattern that removes hard-coded dependencies and enables decoupling by binding at runtime vs compile time.

There are frameworks that bring this functionality to ActionScript, implementing the `[Inject]` metadata tag.

#### Events

Events can bubble up, but are awkward to bubble back down.

It's easy for a child to bubble an event up to an ascendant parent, but generally poor when passing a value back down through descendant children.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I can't use this - it's a customizable avatar animation with body parts each with few different frames. I should specify the question more.